# Display total result count in Articulate

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, umbraco

Anyone know how to find the total results in the List.cshtml page when searching blog posts in Articulate using Umbraco?

I want to display on the first page:

> Your search for "text" matched 35 results. Showing results 1 to 20.
>
> ... [results]
>
> [pager]

Next Page:

> Your search for "text" matched 35 results. Showing results 21 to 35.
>
> ... [results]
>
> [pager]

I'm trying to find the number of total results (in the example here it's 35). I am using the following logic, but it's not giving me the total results because
`@Model.Children.Count()` only gives the count for the results on the page, not the total results.

```
var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)Model.Children.Count() / Model.PageSize);
var currentPage = Math.Max(1, Math.Min(totalPages, Model.Pages.CurrentPageIndex));

var startRecord = ((currentPage - 1) * Model.Pages.PageSize) + 1;
var endRecord = Math.Min(Model.Children.Count(), (startRecord - 1) + Model.Pages.PageSize);
```

I need to replace
`Model.Children.Count()` with the total number of results (totalResults, if you will).
Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the source code:

https://github.com/Shazwazza/Articulate/blob/9b4353756eb0f067aa78cb191b43aaade9103d85/src/Articulate/Controllers/ArticulateController.cs

Looks like you can do: `var totalPosts = Umbraco.GetPostCount(listNode.Id);`

Comment: I can't seem to use `GetPostCount`...?

Comment: it's an extension method, try to add `using Articulate.UmbracoHelperExtensions` to your view

Comment: I can't add that as a using directive because UmbracoHelperExtensions is a type not a namespace. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Bobi Try `using Articulate`?

Comment: @NateBarbettini, yes, I am using that.